# Insert entity in preUpdate event

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to persist a `History` entity whenever a `Message` gets updated. I have too much going on behind the scenes to post all the code here and for it to make sense, but I've basically tracked the issue down to the `UnitOfWork::commit` method. There, the UOW first loops through the `entityInsertions`, and finding nothing, continues on to the `entityUpdates`. There the UOW's `entityInsertions` gets updated, but since it's already past that loop, it doesn't pick up that it still needs to persist some entities. Is there any way to force the UOW to "restart" this process? If so, how? I'm using Doctrine 2.4.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You have to at least post the preUpdate code.

Comment: If you are persisting another entity, I think you need to inform the UoW to schedule your insert as well.

Answer (score 1):

This might be the dirtiest solution ever, but what I ended up doing was basically the following...

1. Create an `onFlush` event subscriber
2. Inject the entire container into the subscriber (seeing as injecting only the entity manager will result in a circular reference error)
3. Loop through the `UnitOfWork`'s `scheduledEntityUpdates` and `scheduledEntityInserts` (I wasn't interested in deletes)
4. Handle each scheduled update or insert which you are interested in (in my case, I marked each entity I was interested in with a `LoggableInterface`, just to know which entities are loggable)
5. Handle the relevant object with a handler chain (This was just my own algorithm, yours may not require this. This was set up to handle logging of different `LoggableInterface` objects in different ways)
6. Persist the entity (the actual history event) via the entity manager, and do the following:

   ```
   $classMeta = $this->entityManager->getClassMetadata(get_class($historyEntity));
   $this->entityManager->getUnitOfWork()->computeChangeSet($classMeta, $historyEntity);
   ```
7. Profit

Hope this helps somebody!